# Modal disappears on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question is a little familiar to previous posts but mine is facing some issues, I just need to be pointed in the right direction. My modal content is coming from a separate page altogether.

Within the modal I have a select option which populates from a database, upon selecting I click on the show button and a table from the database is displayed.

```
<select class="" id="sess_ddl" name="sess_ddl" title="Select Session"> <!--Select Populates from database-->
<?php
     echo "<option disabled selected hidden>Select Session</option>";
     $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sessions ORDER BY Begin desc") or die (mysqli_error());
     while ( $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         echo "<option class='dropdown-content' value='".$row['SessionID'].
              "'data-courses='".$row['Courses'].
              "'>" . (date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['Begin']))) . "&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $row['Courses'] . "</option>";
      } 
?>
</select>
<button class="button button1" id="show_enr" name="show_enr">Show</button> <!--show_enr submit button-->
```

The modal disappears as soon as the form is submitted, I want the fetched table to be displayed within the modal. Tried many things, my final option will be to work without a modal if this doesn't work, since the entire page refreshes on submission. Below is the code for the table which displays on submit, if needed.

```
<div id="enr_learners"> <!--Script shows table on show_enr button click based on selection-->
     <?php 
           if (isset($_POST['show_enr'])) {
                if (!empty($_POST['sess_ddl'])) {    
                    $selected_sess = $_POST['sess_ddl'];
                    $qry1 = "SELECT * FROM enrollments WHERE SessionID = " . $selected_sess . "";
                    $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $qry1) or die (mysqli_error("Please select a session")); 
                        if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
                            echo "<table id='table_id' class='display' style='width:100%;'>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th hidden>ID</th>
                                    <th>SessionID</th>
                                    <th>LearnerID</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        <tbody>";
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td style='text-align:center' hidden>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td style='text-align:center'>" . $row['SessionID'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td style='text-align:center'>" . $row['LearnerID'] . "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                        echo "</tbody>
                              <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>
                               </tfoot>
                            </table>";
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "0 results";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "<div style='margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; padding: 6px 0 7px 20px; background-color:#FADBD8; color:#C0392B;'>Please select a session!</div>";  
                    }
                }
            ?>
            <hr style="margin-bottom:0; padding-bottom:0;" />
        </div>
```

Some help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: add more type="button" in tag your button, default type is submit, it will help you fixed it.

Comment: Replacing the submit button with a button type will allow you to asynchronously load the page data instead of letting it completely refresh by a submit button. Like @sonpham suggested.

Comment: I've tried adding type="button" inside the button tag, also as an input type="button", but then nothing happens on click. Also tried this without the modal, somehow doesn't load page data.

Comment: But with the normal <button> tag it works except the modal disappears